# Invalid Yaml: mapping values are not allowed here

Tags: yaml, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Can anyone help me to figure out the following error while deploying react app on **AWS elastic beanstalk** -

```
2019-08-01 04:37:21    ERROR   The configuration file .ebextensions/nodecommand.
config in application version app-5466-190801_100700 contains invalid YAML or JS
ON. YAML exception: Invalid Yaml: mapping values are not allowed here
 in "<reader>", line 3, column 16:
    option_settings:
                   ^
, JSON exception: Invalid JSON: Unexpected character (/) at position 0.. Update
the configuration file.
2019-08-01 04:37:21    ERROR   Failed to deploy application.
```

Following is my **nodecommand.config** file -

```
option_settings: 
  aws: elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs:  
    NodeCommand: "node server.compiled.js"
```

**Update -**

I followed this link to deploy React app on AWS elastic beanstalk and stuck on above error -

https://medium.com/@wlto/how-to-deploy-an-express-application-with-react-front-end-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk-880ff7245008

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what's shown in the linked tutorial:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs:
    NodeCommand: "node server.compiled.js"
```

This is the YAML in your question:

```
option_settings: 
  aws: elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs:  
    NodeCommand: "node server.compiled.js"
```

Can you spot the difference?

Spoiler: You've put a space after `aws:`. This causes the YAML parser to assume `aws:` is a mapping key with the value `"elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs:"`. However, the next line, which also starts with a mapping key (`NodeCommand`), is indented more, which would only be allowed if the previous line was a mapping key without a value.

If you remove the space, it [correctly parses](https://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=option_settings%3A%0A++aws%3Aelasticbeanstalk%3Acontainer%3Anodejs%3A%0A++++NodeCommand%3A+%22node+server.compiled.js%22&type=json) `aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs` as a mapping key and the following line as its value.

Comment: Thanks much for reply @Jordan, let fix and try it.

Comment: @SachinVairagi did you fixed this issue? I encountered the same error. But the same configuration (without space between `aws:` and the rest of the line) worked to me before. Right now I got the same issue like you.

Answer (score 0):

I was not actually had the problem fixed. I found this document[1] that says because my environment is using Amazon Linux 2, the ebextensions is not recommended. (But some of my ebextensions are still working. I have no idea about that). Instead, Buildfile, Procfile, and platform hooks are recommended. Therefore, I created a Procfile with the following content to make the Node server run with the command `node index.js`.

**Procfile**

```
web: node index.js
```

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html